# Java sometimes prints out others not

Tags: java

I´m programming a mini game. The issue is, java sometimes prints out a result (integer), ther times not. 
Actually when I run it on Debug, it´s always printed. Not on normal Eclipse.
The code below:

```
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("Enemy Pikachu did you a damage of: ");
                Mine.Damage_Rec(Enemy.Tackle());
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Your Pikachu has a health of "+Mine.getHealth());
```

The line which has the issue is within Enemy.Tackle() method. This below:

```
public int Tackle() {

    int damage;

    if(pm1 > 0) {
        damage = AttackT;
        if(damage - Defense > 0) {
            damage -= Defense;
            System.out.println(damage);
            System.out.println();
        }           
        pm1--;
    }
    else {
        damage = 0;
    }       
    return damage;
}
```

The thing is java always calc s the 'damage' but it´s printed out sometimes.

Sorry in advance if I explained something wrong, I´m competly newby in this field ;)

Thank you

Comment: @XtremeBaumer He is still calling the methods without showing us the method itselff

Comment: what is pm1 and is it ever not greater than 0?

Comment: You are showing us very little of what you are requesting in your code

Comment: and damage-Defense?  What is this?

Comment: I am not to familliar with   System.out.println(); but why are there so many without any value???

Comment: You are in a conditionnal block ... if it is not executed, then the condition is `false`, this is that simple. Now, if you want to now why ... you need to provide a [mcve], all I can say is that `pm1 <= 0` OR `AttackT - Defense <= 0`

Answer (score 1):

In your current code, the print statement is in a condition block, where the damage is only printed when it is larger than the defense. This can be solved by printing at the end of the `Tackle()` method.

```
public int Tackle() {

    int damage;

    if(pm1 > 0) {
        damage = AttackT;
        if(damage - Defense > 0) {
            damage -= Defense;
        }           
        pm1--;
    }
    else {
        damage = 0;
    }
    System.out.println(damage);
    return damage;
}
```

Or even better, by printing the result of `Tackle`:

```
int damage = Enemy.Tackle();
System.out.print("Enemy Pikachu did you a damage of: " + damage);
Mine.Damage_Rec(damage);
```

Comment: I agree with you, the only answer possible to this is "_your print is in a condition block_"

Comment: @AxelH you have indeed put it nicely. I changed my answer accordingly.